# In Intellij Idea, how to run tests with different java version than my source java version

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My main source has java version 7

I want to use java 8 from my tests. so i updated the compiler plugin to

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <source>7</source>
      <target>7</target>
      <testSource>8</testSource>
      <testTarget>8</testTarget>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This way I can use java 8 features in unit tests. This works fine when i run the tests using maven from commandline.

But when i run the test directly from intellij, it throws error saying 'lambda expressions are not supported in source 7'

looks like it use the same source version for tests.

How do i configure Intellij to use different java version for tests

Comment: why would you want to keep java 7 AND use lambda's?

Comment: java 7 for src/main/java , java 8 from src/test/java

Comment: how does that answer my question? Why would you use lambda's in a Java 7 project? Want to use lambda's? Just update the java version.

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. if you read the answer in this post , you might understand what I am trying to do. wanted to use java 7 in production code and java 8 in test code

Answer (score 1):

Running tests via another Java interpreter in Maven project is not supported in IntelliJ IDEA yet. Here is the feature request for that:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478

Feel free to vote and follow it for updates.

There is a workaround described by one of the users (separate Maven profile): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-85478#focus=Comments-27-1994481.0-0

By the way, this is supported in Gradle<->IntelliJ IDEA integration:

```
compileTestJava {
    sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running tests with a different JDK version in Maven project is available since IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1